# Why is this just printing out hello world 9 times instead of adding the event onclick?

Tags: javascript

```
let number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
let number2 = document.getElementById("number2");
let number3 = document.getElementById("number3");
let number4 = document.getElementById("number4");
let number5 = document.getElementById("number5");
let number6 = document.getElementById("number6");
let number7 = document.getElementById("number7");
let number8 = document.getElementById("number8");
let number9 = document.getElementById("number9");
let number0 = document.getElementById("number0");
const numbers_ = [number0, number1, number3, number4, number5, number6,
              number7, number8, number9]
function myfunction() {
    console.log("hello world");
};

numbers_.forEach(num => {
    num.addEventListener("click", myfunction())
});
```

This is my code. It is just logging Hello World 9 times on load instead of waiting for the click. Please help.

Comment: also check out `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='number']")` instead of that element selection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you called a function instead of just pass it.
Should be:

```
numbers_.forEach(num => {
    num.addEventListener("click", myfunction)
});
```

Comment: How could I pass a parameter into this function when I click it?

Comment: @Smitty_Code num.addEventListener("click", () => myfunction(...some args...))

or


    num.addEventListener("click", myfunction.bind(null, ...some args...))


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind